# Can PGU (Pygame GUI API) work with pgs4a (PyGame Subset for Android)?

Tags: android, python, pygame, pgu

I have had success so far getting simple PyGame apps to run on Android, using [pgs4a 0.9.4](http://pygame.renpy.org/).  My next experiment was to see if I could use the PyGame GUI widgets in [PGU](http://code.google.com/p/pgu/); unfortunately, this seems not to work, despite a few forum posts suggesting that it should.  Has anyone had success with this?

I am still fumbling a bit learning how to catch and log error information, so following is my attempt at a minimal example demonstrating the problem.  This app just displays a black screen with an error message, if any, in white text.

Note that just importing the PGU module is sufficient to break things.  That is, if I comment out the "from pgu import gui", then things work fine.  The nasty part is that the exception does not seem to be caught cleanly-- the app simply exits immediately after startup-- so I am not sure where in the PGU import the problem lies.

```
import pygame
msg = 'OK'
try:
    from pgu import gui # pass works without error
except Exception as e:
    msg = str(e)

try:
    import android
except ImportError:
    android = None

FPS = 30
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 480, 800

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    if android:
        android.init()
        android.map_key(android.KEYCODE_BACK, pygame.K_ESCAPE)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    surf = font.render(msg, True, (255, 255, 255))
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000 / FPS)
    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.wait()
        if android:
            if android.check_pause():
                android.wait_for_resume()
        if ev.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 255))
            screen.blit(surf, (10, 400))
            pygame.display.flip()
        elif ev.type == pygame.QUIT or (ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and
                                        ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            break
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently read this, but haven't tried it. Looks like you need to copy the additional modules you want to import into the app directory.
http://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/python-on-android/